# Monitoring Freeipa using Prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, telegraf, exporter

i'm trying to monitor my Freeipa server using prometheus.
can i use LDAP exporter with telegraf plugin to collect freeipa metrics and then send them to prometheus?

Thanks in advance.